# Passing puppet exec command to a variable

Tags: ruby, sed, puppet

I have an ssl cert file that I want to convert into a string before uploading using puppet. Below is what I have:

```
class ssl_cert {

  $cert='domain.com.crt';
  $key='domain.com.key';

  file { $urlcert :
    ensure => present,
  }

  file { $key :
    ensure => present,
  }

  exec { 'Use $cert':
    path    => '/opt/',
    require => File[$cert],
    command => "/bin/sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r*\n/\\n/g' $cert",
  }

  exec { 'Use $key':
    path    => '/opt/',
    require => File[$key],
    command => "/bin/sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r*\n/\\n/g' $key",
  }

  #Upload ssl cert for vhost
  brocadevtm::ssl_server_keys { 'domain.com' :
    ensure          => present,
    basic__note     => '',
    basic__private  => $cert,
    basic__public   => $key,
  }
}
```

Is there a way to pass the exec command (command => "/bin/sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r*\n/\n/g' $cert",) to a variable which can be called later and used for the values  basic__private  => ' ' and basic__public => ' '? as it is now, those values are just picking up domain.com.crt and domain.com.key from the variables above but I want to use the output of the command instead and not the file.

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.9/custom_facts.html

Comment: No. The commands encapsulated by `Exec` resources are run only after a catalog is compiled.  Puppet variables are evaluated and used (only) as part of the catalog-building process, so their values are needed before any `Exec` runs.  As @MattSchuchard implied, if you want the catalog builder to incorporate information about the current state of the target machine into that machine's own catalog, then *facts* are the mechanism for conveying that information to the catalog builder.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I have put together a fact, where do I place the .rb file and also, how do I call the fact in my manifest?